# Does anyone know some Java class that return a operating system friendly filename?

Tags: java, linux, file, file-io

I have an uploader in my web page, but some people upload files named like "compañia 15% *09.jpg" and i have problems when the filenames are like that one.

I would like to found a class that returns for that example something like this: "compania1509.jpg".

Answer (score 4):

In other words, you'd like to get rid of all characters outside the [printable ASCII range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)? You can use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with a pattern of `[^\x20-\x7e]` for this.

```
name = name.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
```

If you want to get rid of spaces as well, then start with `\x21` instead. You can even restrict it to Word-characters only. Use `\W` to indicate "any non-word" character. The name will then match only alphanumericals and the underscore.

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

Comment: That's one way to solve it, but it's overkill for many OSes. There's no reason a filename can't contain `ñ` on most OSes, for instance.

Comment: @T.J: that would then be more a question/answer for Superuser :)