# Remove "empty" character from String

Tags: java, character

I'm using a framwork which returns malformed Strings with "empty" characters from time to time.

"foobar" for example is represented by:
[,f,o,o,b,a,r]

The first character is NOT a whitespace (' '), so a System.out.printlin() would return "foobar" and not " foobar". Yet, the length of the String is 7 instead of 6. Obviously this makes most String methods (equals, split, substring,..) useless. Is there a way to remove empty characters from a String?

I tried to build a new String like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (final char character : malformedString.toCharArray()) {
  if (Character.isDefined(character)) {
    sb.append(character);
  }
}
sb.toString();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Same with the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (final Character character : malformedString.toCharArray()) {
  if (character != null) {
    sb.append(character);
  }
}
sb.toString();
```

I also can't check for an empty character like this:

```
   if (character == ''){
     //
   }
```

Obviously there is something wrong with the String .. but I can't change the framework I'm using or wait for them to fix it (if it is a bug within their framework). I need to handle this String and sanatize it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is it then?  Try writing out the unicode number of each character (just cast the char to an int).

Comment: Is that a U+FEFF character maybe? Then it might be the byte order mark from a file stored as UTF-*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probably the [NULL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) which is represented by `\0`. You can get rid of it by [`String#trim()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29).

To nail down the exact codepoint, do so:

```
for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.printf("U+%04x ", (int) c);
}
```

Then you can find the exact character [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm).

---

**Update:** as per the update:

> Anyone know of a way to just include a range of valid characters instead of excluding 95% of the UTF8 range?

You can do that with help of regex. See the answer of @polygenelubricants here and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069634/does-anyone-know-some-java-class-that-return-a-operating-system-friendly-filename/3069681#3069681).

On the other hand, you can also just fix the problem in its root instead of workarounding it. Either update the files to get rid of the BOM mark, it's a legacy way to distinguish UTF-8 files from others which is nowadays worthless, or use a `Reader` which recognizes and skips the BOM. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java).

Answer (score 21):

Regex would be an appropriate way to sanitize the string from unwanted Unicode characters in this case.

```
String sanitized = dirty.replaceAll("[\uFEFF-\uFFFF]", "");
```

This will replace all `char` in `\uFEFF-\uFFFF` range with the empty string.

The `[...]` construct is called a *character class*, e.g. `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels, `[^aeiou]` matches anything but.

You can do one of these two approaches:

- `replaceAll("[`*<sub>`blacklist`</sub>*`]", "")`
- `replaceAll("[^`*<sub>`whitelist`</sub>*`]", "")`

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 7):

A very simple way to remove the UTF-8 BOM from a string, using substring as Denis Tulskiy suggested.  No looping needed.  Just checks the first character for the mark and skips it if needed.

```
public static String removeUTF8BOM(String s) {
    if (s.startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

I needed to add this to my code when using the Apache HTTPClient EntityUtil to read from a webserver.  The webserver was not sending the blank mark but it was getting pulled in while reading the input stream.  Original article can be found [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, you saved me a lot of time :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Johannes Rössel. It actually was '\uFEFF'

The following code works:

```
 final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (final char character : body.toCharArray()) {
       if (character != '\uFEFF') {
          sb.append(character);
       }
     }  
 final String sanitzedString = sb.toString();
```

Anyone know of a way to just include a range of valid characters instead of excluding 95% of the UTF8 range?

Comment: You should then define "valid characters" more precisely.

Comment: this is inefficient, just check if the first character is FEFF and use substring, `String.trim()` will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

trim left or right removes white spaces. does it has a colon before space?

even more:
a=(long) string[0]; will show u the char code, and u can use replace() or substring.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:-

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char character : myString.toCharArray()) {
        int i = (int) character;
        if (i > 0 && i <= 256) {
            sb.append(character);
        }
    }  
    return sb.toString();
```

The int value of my NULL characters was in the region of 8103 or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `replace`:

```
s.replace("\u200B", "")
```

or

```
s.replace("\uFEFF", "")
```

Kotlin:

```
s.filter { it == '\u200B' }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        your code....
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply **malformedString.trim()** will solve the issue.

Comment: No, it doesn't:

`"\uFEFFTYPE".trim().equals("\uFEFFTYPE")`

Answer (score -3):

You could check for the whitespace like this:

```
if (character.equals(' ')){ // }
```

Comment: The question already establishes that the character is not a space.

Comment: The question does say that it is not whitespace; however, in the three code examples given he is using comparison operators to check for the character, and if I am not mistaken you cannot use comparison operators to check for a certain character because they are checking if you are referencing the same place in memory not the character code. It was just a helpful suggestion / option based on the code provided.

Comment: I see where you're coming from - for a Character object, using equals() is the right thing to do. I tend to keep to chars when dealing which characters, and with a char you *can* use == since it's a primitive type.