# An "Empty" Character Extracted from a PDF

Tags: java, character, pdfbox

I recently tried to use PDFBox to extract text from a PDF file. It works fine for most PDFs, but for one PDF (which unfortunately I am not permitted to share), all of the periods in the sentences do not get extracted out. Instead, I get phrases like the following:

```
...what it would be It’ll be important later on...
```

It looks like instead of a period-space it is just a space, but it's not (at least on Mac OS X). If you copy the text into a text editor and start moving the text cursor through the phrase, there is an "empty character" right after the "t" in "feet". To reproduce:

- Place the cursor right before the letter "t" in "feet" and press the
  right arrow key. The cursor moves one step to the right.
- Press the right arrow key again, you stay right where you are.
- Press the right arrow key one more time, you continue to the other side of the space.
- Continuing to press the right arrow key behaves as expected

It appears that PDFBox extracted some sort of "empty character" in place of a period. I've tried to replace it a few different ways but have had no luck:

```
String oldText = text;
text = text.replace('\u0000', '.'); //Unicode null
text = text.replace('\0', '.'); //C null
System.out.println(oldText.equals(text)); //Returns true
//Also tried text.replace(null, '.'), but it doesn't compile
```

What is this "empty character" and how can I replace it with the text that is supposed to be there?

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396779/531762) suggested that the character might be a character such as `\uFEFF`, but trying to replace it with a regex as suggested did not work.

Comment: The fact that you can't share the document (and felt compelled to say so) makes the excerpt, "places his feet Either way" somewhat creepy :-P

Comment: Haha, yeah! Perhaps that wasn't the best example to share because it was out of context. I've changed the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After realizing that the character wasn't `\uFEFF` or `\u0000`, two values of unicode that other Stack Overflow users had run into, I decided to run a test to figure out what the code actually was. Using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220476/531762) to determine what the unicode value was, I figured out that the mysterious character was `\u0008`, which is "[backspace](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm)". Why that would have been pulled from the PDF, I don't know, but `text = text.replace('\u0008', '.')` now replaces it with the missing periods.